# Pinescript - Decimal Input Option

Tags: pine-script

I want to have the option in the settings to input how many Decimals show for current price on a label, but cant get it to work using label.new

So for the input option, it would be something like

```
DecOption = input(title="Decimal Option", options=["No Decimal", "One Decimal", "Two Decimal"],
     defval="No Decimal")
```

Statically decimal output is not a problem using "#.##" ... but having it selectable as a input in the settings is harder for me, any suggestions ?

```
//@version=4
study("Current Price", overlay=true)

symbolName = input(title="Type Symbol Or Leave Blank", defval="BTC")
    
sizeOption = input(title="Label Size", type=input.string,options=["Auto", "Huge", "Large", "Normal", "Small", "Tiny"],defval="Large")
     
labelSize = (sizeOption == "Huge") ? size.huge :
     (sizeOption == "Large") ? size.large :
     (sizeOption == "Small") ? size.small :
     (sizeOption == "Tiny") ? size.tiny :
     (sizeOption == "Auto") ? size.auto :
         size.normal

l = label.new(bar_index, na, text= symbolName +tostring( close, " $ #"), 
  color=close >= open ? color.green : color.red, 
  textcolor=color.white,
  style=label.style_labeldown, yloc=yloc.abovebar, size=labelSize)

label.delete(l[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string is explained in the reference manual for the [tostring()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_tostring) function.
*Format string. Optional argument, default value is '#.##########'.

To display trailing zeros use 0 instead of a '#' symbol. For example, '#.000'.*

Example with 4 decimals:

```
//@version=4
study("Current Price", overlay=true)

symbolName = input(title="Type Symbol Or Leave Blank", defval="BTC")
    
sizeOption = input(title="Label Size", type=input.string,options=["Auto", "Huge", "Large", "Normal", "Small", "Tiny"],defval="Large")
     
labelSize = (sizeOption == "Huge") ? size.huge :
     (sizeOption == "Large") ? size.large :
     (sizeOption == "Small") ? size.small :
     (sizeOption == "Tiny") ? size.tiny :
     (sizeOption == "Auto") ? size.auto :
         size.normal

l = label.new(bar_index, na, text= symbolName +tostring( close, " $ #.0000"), 
  color=close >= open ? color.green : color.red, 
  textcolor=color.white,
  style=label.style_labeldown, yloc=yloc.abovebar, size=labelSize)

label.delete(l[1])
```

**Edit 1** : in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436181/pinescript-decimal-input-option/66445583?noredirect=1#comment117471352_66445583)
This example gives you the option to input the number of decimals as an integer.
It can also limit the number of decimals by the [Min tick value for the current symbol](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dmintick).
You can also decide wether or not to show trailing zero's for the decimals.
When you leave the symbol input blank, it will default to the charted symbol name.

```
//@version=4
study("Current Price", "CP", overlay=true)

LS0 = "Auto", LS1 = "Huge", LS2 = "Large", LS3 = "Normal", LS4 = "Small", LS5 = "Tiny"

var string  i_symbolName    = input("BTC",  "Type Symbol Or Leave Blank",   type=input.string)
var int     i_decimals      = input(4,      "Decimal option",               type=input.integer, minval=0, maxval=10)
var bool    i_limit_mintick = input(false,  "Decimals limited by mintick",  type=input.bool)
var bool    i_trailing_zero = input(true,   "Show decimal trailing zero's", type=input.bool)
var string  i_sizeOption    = input(LS2,    "Label Size",                   type=input.string,  options=[LS0, LS1, LS2, LS3, LS4, LS5])

var string  labelText       = na
var color   labelColor      = na
var string  labelSize       =  (i_sizeOption == LS0) ? size.auto   :
                               (i_sizeOption == LS1) ? size.huge   :
                               (i_sizeOption == LS2) ? size.large  :
                               (i_sizeOption == LS3) ? size.normal :
                               (i_sizeOption == LS4) ? size.small  :
                               (i_sizeOption == LS5) ? size.tiny   :
                               size.normal

var label   l               = label.new(na, na, na, yloc=yloc.abovebar, style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.white, size=labelSize)
var string  strFormatBase   = " $ #"
var string  strFormat       = na
var string  symbolName      = i_symbolName == "" ? syminfo.ticker : i_symbolName

if barstate.islast
    strFormat := strFormatBase + (i_decimals ? "." : "")

    for i = 1 to i_limit_mintick ? str.length(tostring(syminfo.mintick))-2 : i_decimals
        strFormat := strFormat + (i_trailing_zero ? "0" : "#")
    
    labelText  := symbolName + tostring(close, strFormat)
    labelColor := close >= open ? color.green : color.red

    label.set_x(l, bar_index)
    label.set_text(l, labelText)
    label.set_color(l, labelColor)
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, but thats not what i am looking for, i already knew i can make the decimals static using #.# etc ..... what i am looking for is have a input option for the different decimal amounts, so a user can input in the settings how many decimal they want to show on the label for the different Symbols/tickers like this ..                                                                                                                                                          DecOption = input(title="Decimal Option", options=["No Decimal", "One Decimal", "Two Decimal"], defval="No Decimal")

Comment: Updated my answer. See "Edit 1" section.

Comment: Wow that is awsome, thanks so much. I just reliazed that to keep it showing current price i have to run it on a 1 second chart as we are using close. i don't think there is any other way to show current price data, no matter what timeframe you are on is there ?

Comment: No need to run it on a 1sec chart. It will work on any timeframe. On any live chart, `close` just means the latest (current) price. Each time that realtime `close` prices changes, the script is executed and recalculated. So it'll always show the current live price in the label.

Comment: Sorry for only getting back to you now, i missed your reply, and i have only got back on to this idea now.  Ok so yes you are right, can see it will work on anyTF, but its interesting, when price is rising the label prints the changes in priec nice and smooth and keeps up. But for some reason whenever price turns and goes down, the price hangs on the last highest price and doesn't seem to catch up for a long while on price going down. Any reason for that at all ? ... its make no sense that it would do this, but it is

Comment: That's weird. I'm not seeing the behaviour that you describe. Mine keeps up with both up and down moves. On which ticker and timeframe are you seeing this anomaly?

Comment: Seeing it on the BTC 1 min TF, so lots of movement in price, and always down it hangs, as soon as price turns back up it corrects...  also when it is bouncing between say 54500.5 and 54500 you can see the label changing colour from green to red, but not the price.. and then if the price then drops more, the price hangs at 54500.5 ...  i checked it on phone as well that has different internet connections, just in case it was my computer making a issue, but same issue ... wish i could post a screen shot to show you

Comment: Actually BTC 1 min, 15 min or 1 hour makes no difference, when price goes down the price is hanging

Comment: I have no explanation for this. I've tried it on several BTC crosses on several exchanges, and they all work on my end.